# APC Smart-UPS 750 self test stays at 100%

Tags: apc

I have a previously reliable APC Smart-UPS 750 that recently went into "REPLACEBATT" status. I obediently bought a new battery and fitted it. As per procedure I then shut down the APC daemon (CentOS 6) and fired up apctest. The test started with no issues, but stayed at 100%. I even went as far as checking to see if the computer had been unplugged and was being powered form elsewhere, but no. I finally aborted the test and fired the APC daemon back up again, only to find the actual battery level was 2%. I watched the battery charge back up to 100% over the next hour or two and ran the test again. It again stuck at 100%, but this time I only left it running a couple of minutes and then aborted, to find it was actually about 75%.

I have been running the Smart-UPS 750 as my weapon of choice for years and have them installed all over the place, but I have never seen one do this. Has anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did APC support have to say?

Comment: I don't have a support contract so have not contacted them.